# Nested for - batch

Tags: windows, batch, script, cmd.exe

I have a little problem with this code:

```
for %%A in (tmp1,tmp2,tmp3) do (
    for /R C:\%%A %%B in (*.txt) do copy %0 "%%~B" /Y
)
```

I get no error message or anything like that, the code just runs but doesn't work.
Can anyone give me a light? Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to do? How have you been calling this?

Comment: I can approve: your script contains no evident syntax incorrectness but `%%A` does not expand in the `for /R C:\%%A ...` command at all. Verified on _Win8_ with `echo on`, regardless of _delayed expansion_ is enabled or disabled. A workaround with `echo`ed and extended output: `for /f "tokens=*" %%B in ('dir /B /S "C:\%%~A\*.txt"') do echo "%%~A" copy "%~0" "%%~B" /Y`. I do not want _answer_ your question as I don't know reason (occasion) of the problem. Let answer someone smarter:) BTW: maybe this question should be asked at [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com/) rather than here...

Answer (score 1):

There are many phases to the batch parser. See [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133/1012053) for more info.

The FOR statement options are parsed prior to FOR variable expansion, so you cannot use FOR variables (or delayed expansion) within FOR options.

I see two workarounds:

1) PUSHD to the root folder so that `/R` works properly with the current directory.

 I like this option the best.

```
for %%A in (tmp1,tmp2,tmp3) do (
  pushd c:\%%A
  for /R %%B in (*.txt) do copy %0 "%%~B" /Y
  popd
)
```

2) Transfer the value to a CALL argument

```
for %%A in (tmp1,tmp2,tmp3) do call :copyLoop c:\%%A
exit /b

:copyLoop
for /r %1 %%B in (*.txt) do copy %0 "%%~B" /Y
exit /b
```

Comment: Thanks, dbenham!
I tried to use with the pushd command and it worked